# Allow www. subdomain with free azurewebsites.net URL

Tags: dns, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Websites URL at http://mysite.azurewebsites.net.  Attempting to browse to http://www.[mysite].azurewebsites.net/ results in a DNS lookup failure, with the error code in Chrome of "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

I've attempted to add www.[mysite].azurewebsites.net in "Manage custom domains", but receive the message "The host name www.[mysite].azurewebsites.net is invalid."

[image]

Note that I don't have a custom domain and I'm happy to use the .azurewebsites.net URL, I simply would like the users who add "www." to the URL they've been given to resolve to the correct URL.

Is this possible with Azure Websites without requiring a custom domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The menu from your screenshot can be used to configure any domain, you own, to point to your azurewebsite, this is not what you want.

Your "website" is a subdomain (level 3) of domain azurewebsites.net, where "azurewebsites" is a level 2 domain and "net" is the TLD. "www" is a subdoamin and normally used as (level 3) subdomain in ealier days to point out, that you are using the World Wide Web. This is not necessary and it does not make sense to create a level 4 subdomain "www". I don't even think, level 4 subdomains are supported by azure anyway.

Comment: So, it is not possible for www.[mysite].azurewebsites.net/ to resolve?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible.

If you would be able to create any level 4 subdomain there, it could be resolved. But you are not able to do so. Nevertheless the purpose of a subdomain "www" is, to use it as a level 3 subdomain, here "www.azurewebsites.net", that works, because it was configured by Microsoft. You can only control the name of your level 3 "mysite" subdomain.